# Ugaritic characters are only displayed in Safari browser

Tags: utf-8, xhtml

I'm doing a template of the equivalence between Ugaritic (an old Semitic language) and Latin characters in `XHTML` page. I tried to use `HTML` Entity decimal and hex given on this [website](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1039a/index.htm). But Ugaritic characters are only displayed in Safari browser.

`XHTML` header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Transliteration of Ugaritic letters</title>
</head>
```

An example using both `HTML` Entity decimal and hex

```
      <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Sign</th>
            <th>Letter</th>
            <th>Latin character</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&#x10380;</td>
            <td>aleph</td>
            <td>ʾ</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&#66433;</td>
            <td>beta</td>
            <td>b</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Any idea why it doesn't work? In advance, thank you.

Comment: Fonts? Browsers use the fonts that they, the OS and the user set up and/or the fonts that the CSS requests to be downloaded.

Comment: Yes, of course!!! Thanks for the reminder @TomBlodget. It works now after adding in `.css`: `@font-face {src: url(https://www.google.com/get/noto/#sans-ugar)}`

Comment: If that is the answer, it's strange that Safari can display the characters without needing the `@font-face`. Or in other words, if the characters exist in at least one locally installed font as well, how come the other browsers can't find them?